# How to edit Apache Forbidden error "You don't have permission to access this resource.Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe"

Tags: linux, apache, server, apache2, errordocument

I'm trying to setting up custom errors over **Apache2.4** (Over Suse **Linux**) in my site (my computer).

The highest problem I encountered is when I set up a directory with flag "no permission" with chmod like

```
sudo chmod 000 /path/rootapachefolder/subfolder
```

to set up the folder as Forbidden (Access denied for all World and also for Apache)

The server gives me back the error

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access this resource.Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe</p>
</body>
</html>
```

and seems **not follow the line** putted up in `.htaccess` file **in the root folder**

```
ErrorDocument 403 /errors/403
```

but the `ErrorDocument` line it's followed when I make a folder with a `.htaccess` file like this

```
Require all denied
```

**EDIT:**

Also note that if the command `sudo chmod 000 /path/rootapachefolder/subfolder/file.ext` is executed for a file and not for a folder [and obviously the file has an extension different from php that it have to be runned up in a processor (something like .doc)] the Apache `ErrorDocument` directive it's followed. So the error comes from the inability of Apache2 to read the `.htaccess` file in the subfolder, also if there's an `.htaccess` file in the upper directory or root directory.

This head it's going a little bit mad and it's smoking.

Why this?
And how to solve it and make it follow the error in ErrorDocument?
Or, if it's impossibile, there's an opportunity to edit the default Apache error?

Comment: I replicated your issue with docker but I was not able to fix it. That is why I hate apache. Could you try nginx?

Comment: With `chmod 000` you are denying access on `/path/folder` to the whole world, including Apache

Comment: What is your expectation from `sudo chmod 000 /path/folder`. Did you make an error posting that command in your question? If not, what do you expect will be the result?